# How to remove Trailing, Unused Query String with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL with a trailing, empty GET query string like this:

*mydomain.com/news/?=/*

I've been able to gain access to modify this in the CMS and as such I'm wondering how I might write a Rewrite rule in my htaccess file to divert this to:

*mydomain.com/news/ or mydomain.com/news*

I do appreciate that the ultimate solution is to remove the problem in the CMS but given that's not an option, can you suggest any htaccess fixes? Bear in mind that there are already some htaccess rules, so I'd ideally want something that addresses this scenario, rather than a blanket rewrite rule that will potentially interfere with the rest of the site.

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? Have you tried to learn `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to Zerkms. Mod rewrites are not my area of expertise, hence my question.

Comment: Can you show us your htaccess file. There must be a reason why it's adding trailing slashes and definitely has to be mod_rewrite as zerkms has mentioned.

Comment: "Mod rewrites are not my area of expertise" --- what is your area of expertise so that you cannot learn trivial things?

Comment: I am not asking you to fix it, I am asking you to fiddle or edit your question with the code that is inside your .htaccess file from your website. http://www.newwebsite.co.nz/.htaccess if you don't know where it is.

Comment: I've resolved the PHP. Thanks Attis, problem resolved as soon as you submit, often the way. We all have areas of expertise and we have deadlines. No time to become awesome at everything Zerk